# What are the differences between instance final fields from Java and readonly instance fields from C#?

Tags: java, c#

In general - equivalent of `final` field in Java is the `readonly` field in C#. But the more I read about C# the more I see that there are some differences in details.

I've found myself two differences:

## Fields marked as readonly assigned as part of definition can be reasigned in constructor

In Java it is not possible to do that with final fields. Examples:

### Example - C Sharp

```
public class Foo
{
    public readonly int a = 1;

    public Foo()
    {
        a = 2;
    }
}
```

and now

```
Foo f = new Foo();
Console.WriteLine(f.a);
```

will give us `2` as an output

*(side question - is this behavior can be actualy used for something useful? As far as I know I cannot assign value to base class' readonly field in dervied class)*

### Example - Java

```
class Foo {
    private final int i = 3;

    public Foo() {
        // compilation error
        // i = 2;
    }
}
```

## Orders of initalization of readonly and final fields in class hierarchy are different in both languages

- In Java it will go from **base class to dervied**.
- In C# it will go from **derived class to base**.

### Example - C Sharp

*Based on article Eric Lippert: [Why Do Initializers Run In The Opposite Order As Constructors? Part One](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/15/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-one/)*:

```
public class Print
{
    public Print(string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}

public class Base
{
    private readonly Print @base = new Print("Base class");
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    private readonly Print derived = new Print("Derived class");
}
```

In case of calling `new Derived()` we will see:

```
Derived class
Base class
```

As far as I understood - this order of initalization guarantees that readonly fields are **always initalized** before usage.  In case of following code *(based on second part of Eric's article - [Why Do Initializers Run In The Opposite Order As Constructors? Part Two](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/02/18/why-do-initializers-run-in-the-opposite-order-as-constructors-part-two/))*:

```
public class Foo
{
}

public class Base
{
    public Base()
    {
        if (this is Derived)
        {
            ((Derived)this).danger();
        }
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    private readonly Foo derived = new Foo();
    public void danger()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("access: {0}", derived.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Calling `new Derived()` is safe.

### Example - Java

Similar code in Java:

```
class Print {
    public Print(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}

class Base {
    private final Print base = new Print("Base class");
}

class Derived extends Base {
    private final Print derived = new Print("Derived class");
}
```

Call `new Derived()` will result with:

```
Base class
Derived class
```

So in case of following code:

```
class Base {
    public Base() {
        if (this instanceof Derived) {
            ((Derived)this).danger();
        }
    }
}

class Derived extends Base  {
    private final Foo field = new Foo();

    public void danger()
    {
        System.out.println("access: " + field.hashCode());
    }
}
```

The call `new Derived()` will result with `NullPointerException`

## Question

My question is: Are there other differences (even small ones) between Java's final fields and readonly fields in C# ? To make question more clear - I have in mind **only** final instance fields in Java (so no static finals, no final variables, no other final "thigs")

Comment: Your question is arguably too broad. It also could be answered by you simply reading the respective specifications for Java and C#. If you want a good answer, I suggest you do that first. Then post a more specific question, describing what specifically about the details in the specifications you still don't understand.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for pointing me what can be improved in. For my defense - I thought my question is specific (difference between very exact usage of specific keyword in java and specific keyword in c#) I tried also to show this is not question like „what is an equivalent of Java’s final keyword in C#” - since those have answers already. I’ve tried to show that I’ve done research before asking and what I’ve found. Also I’m not fully agree with „by you simple reading the respective specifications” - but like I said, thank you for pointing me bad practices instead of just casting downvote.